# In Exercises1–6, find a basis for the solution space of the ho mogeneous linear system, and find the dimension of that space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

for number 1, I tried reducing the matrix to solve for x1, x2, x3, but i got a row of 0's, so I'm not sure what to do after that... and what exactly if i have a solution? i saw an example of having as many vectors as there were parameters like you would in #2, but there are no parameters required, so how would do this correctly?

maybe I have to write the solution to to the system as 1 vector in a set like {(x,y,z)}, and that would make it 1 dimension? I'm still having trouble finding the solution if theres a row of 0 though

Comment: Have you learned Gaussian elimination?  Back substitution?  What to do in back substitution if there is a non-leading column?

Comment: guassian yes, however I'm not quite sure what to do in this situation if you have a row of 0s for guassian? If you could tell me I'm curious.. and I forgot about back substitution, didn't know I could use it in homogeneous systems. am I supposed to break out of a guassian problem and start solving it with back substitution?

Comment: if you have a zero row, then you have two conditions (equations) for 3 variables. Fix a convenient one (say, x). If you consider it fixed, you can express the other two (say, y, z) as a function of x. As x is free, you get a general solution by letting x assume any valid value.

Comment: when you say fix and free, you mean solve for x right? and I kinda tried to do that, but every time i row reduce it i come up with the rows |010| and |-101| which gives me nothing but y=0, z=x......

Comment: @JL: Well if your reduction is correct (I did not check), then that's the solution! (also, if you want users you address to see what you said, you need to add a '@username').

Comment: @gnometorule oh I see! so in that case is I'd think the basis is {(z,0,x)} with dimension 1.. but the book says {(1,0,1)} dimension 1. how do the z and x translate to 1?

Comment: If it's one-dimensional, space is spanned by $\lambda v_0$ for a basis vector $v_0$. And you just calculated (w/o noticing) that the solution space is $ \{ x \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} | x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ as you can pull the x out (remember, you calculated that x=z, so in your last comment, you should have said { (x,0,x) } ). Think about this, and I recommend read your notes again. (sorry for interim typos  @JL)

Comment: right.. i see how the z = x .. so the vector in the set starts off as {(x,0,x)} then {(x,0,x)}... but I'm having trouble seeing the physical step that allows it to go from x's to 1s, are you aloud to factor out a scalar in a vector in a set? but even if you did, why is there a 0 in the z position of your solution space?

Comment: @JL: The z coordinate is 1 (there was an original typo saying 0). As to why you can pull this out, by basic rules of vector algebra, $\begin{pmatrix} \lambda a_1 \\ \lambda a_2 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda a_n \end{pmatrix} = \lambda \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{pmatrix}.$ In your case: $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ 0 \\ x \end{pmatrix} = x \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. You need to go back to your notes if this doesn't make sense - you essentially solved the exercise, just need to see you did. :)

Comment: alright I missphrased that, i know i can factor scalars out of vectors, but I'm wondering how the factored out x would suddenly go away when you write it in basis notation? Im not 100% but I think you dont put scalars in the notation of a set, so I can see why there wouldnt be an x there, but why are you alloud to just make the x vanish in the final basis notation?

Comment: I may just be being too anal about this, I could just remember to always knock off the x/y/z when writing out the set notation. thanks for the help.